# how to sort the business id based on sort function in python

Tags: python, sorting, rating

Example:

```
enter code here
businesses: [
    Business(id=1, rating=4.0, vegan_friendly=True, price=4, distance=10.0),
    Business(id=2, rating=2.5, vegan_friendly=False, price=2, distance=5.0),
    Business(id=3, rating=4.5, vegan_friendly=False, price=1, distance=1.0),
    Business(id=4, rating=3.0, vegan_friendly=True, price=2, distance=3.4),
    Business(id=5, rating=4.5, vegan_friendly=true, price=1, distance=6.3),
    Business(id=6, rating=3.5, vegan_friendly=True, price=2, distance=1.2),
]
```

sort the rating from highest to low based on id

Comment: What have you tried already?

Comment: It is already sorted by id, clarify/confirm if you wanted to sort it by rating instead ? And also show and edit the question to shw the code you tried yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# To sort the list in place...
businesses.sort(key=lambda x: x.id, reverse=True)

# To return a new list, use the sorted() built-in function...
newlist = sorted(businesses, key=lambda x: x.id, reverse=True)
```

Comment: when i want to use the code with few filters how will that work    def filter_and_sort_businesses(
    businesses: List[Business],
    only_vegan_friendly: bool = False,
    max_price: Optional[int] = None,
    max_distance: Optional[float] = None,
) -> List[int]:

Comment: @komal vyas please how did you solve this

Answer (score 0):

you can use python built-in method `sorted` and provide a sorting `key`:

```
businesses = [
    Business(id=1, rating=4.0, vegan_friendly=True, price=4, distance=10.0),
    Business(id=2, rating=2.5, vegan_friendly=False, price=2, distance=5.0),
    Business(id=3, rating=4.5, vegan_friendly=False, price=1, distance=1.0),
    Business(id=4, rating=3.0, vegan_friendly=True, price=2, distance=3.4),
    Business(id=5, rating=4.5, vegan_friendly=true, price=1, distance=6.3),
    Business(id=6, rating=3.5, vegan_friendly=True, price=2, distance=1.2),
]
businesses_sorted = sorted(businesses, key=lambda business: business.id)
```

to reverse list use `reverse` flag:

```
businesses_sorted_reversed = sorted(businesses, key=lambda business: business.id, reverse=True)
```